# How to parse nested array insided a json object

Tags: android, retrofit

So I made an api in laravel and it returns a response like this:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ],
        "mobile": [
            "The mobile has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

Can somebody show me how to get the specific values from errors?

Answer (score 0):

You may create model representing your error json and use Gson to parse it. Here is some short example.

```
data class Errors(
    val email: List<String>,
    val phone: List<String>
)

data class YourErrorModel(
    val message: String,
    val errors: Errors
)

fun parseError(response: Response<*>): YourErrorModel? {
    val errorBody = response.errorBody()?.string() ?: return null //No error body present
    return Gson().fromJson(errorBody, YourErrorModel::class.java)
}
```

Also don't forget to handle nullable types in your response. And i suggest you to return just string, not array if that is exact error for field.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
JSONObject errorObject = yourJSONObject.optJSONObject("errors");
if (errorObject != null){
    JSONArray emailMsgArray = errorObject.getJSONArray("email");
    JSONArray mobileMsgArray = errorObject.getJSONArray("mobile");

    String emailMsg= emailMsgArray.getString(0);
    String mobileMsg= mobileMsgArray .getString(0);
}
```